# C++ strlen() initialized char array

Tags: c++, c-strings, strlen

Quick question.

I couldn't find why an initialized char array returns this value. I understand that the **strlen()** function will only return the amount of characters inside of an array, and not the size, but why will it return **61** if there are no characters in it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 50;

    char test[MAX];
    int length = strlen(test);

    cout << "The current \'character\' length of the test array is: " << length << endl;
    // returns "61"
        // why?

    cin >> test; //input == 'nice'
    length = strlen(test);

    cout << "The new \'character\' length of the test array is: " << length << endl;
// returns 4 when 'nice' is entered.    
// this I understand.


    return 0;
}
```

This was driving me nuts during a project because I would be trying to use a loop to feed information into a character array but strlen() would always return an outrageous value until I initialized the array as:

**char testArray[50] = '';**

instead of

**char testArray[50];**

I got these results using Visual Studio 2015

Thanks!

Comment: `char test[Max];` defines an array but not it's content, which remains uninitialized until written to. Reading uninitialized data is undefined behavior. That means `strlen` can return 61 today, 5 tomorrow, crash, or do anything else. To be clear, `strlen` returns the number of characters before the character `'\0'` is found.

Comment: What did you expect to happen and why?

Comment: Why do you think an uninitialized array can't contain outrageous values?

Comment: Also, what do you expect will happen if they input `Lopado­temacho­selacho­galeo­kranio­leipsano­drim­hypo­trimmato­silphio­parao­melito­katakechy­meno­kichl­epi­kossypho­phatto­perister­alektryon­opte­kephallio­kigklo­peleio­lagoio­siraio­baphe­tragano­pterygon` ?

Comment: @M.M Sadness...

Comment: @George Or celebrations in the ruined, radioactive streets if this code is in the command console for [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator).

Comment: @M.M I was more or less expecting strlen() to realize that there weren't any characters in the array and return 0.. I thought that declaring the array was the same to initializing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the basic misunderstanding is that - unlike in other languages - in C, locally defined variables are not initialised with any value, neither with empty strings, nor with 0, nor with any `<undefined>` or whatever unless you explicitly initialise them.

Note that accessing uninitialised variables actually is "undefined behaviour"; it may lead to "funny" and non-deterministic results, may crash, or might even be ignored at all.

A very common behaviour of such programs (though clearly not guaranteed!) is that if you write

```
char test[50];
int length = strlen(test);
```

then `test` will point to some memory, which is reserved in the size of `50` bytes yet filled with arbitrary characters, not necessarily `\0`-characters at all. Hence, `test` will probably not be "empty" in the sense that the first character is a `\0` as it would be with a really empty string `""`. If you now access `test` by calling `strlen(test)` (which is actually UB, as said), then `strlen` may just go through this arbitrarily filled memory, and it might detect a `\0` within the first `50` characters, or it might detect the first `\0` much after having exceeded the `50` bytes.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification everyone, I now understand that simply declaring something doesn't mean it's initialized- and trying to read uninitialized variables will screw with c++        Thanks Stephan and Francois, Russian guy, and the other sarcastic guys. Made me laugh!

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you have found your answer, but you have to understand how does this thing works, I think.

```
char test[MAX];
```

In this line of code you have just declared an array of MAX chars. You will get random values in this array until you initialize it. The strlen function just walks through the memory until it find 0 value. So, since values in your array are random, the result of this function is random. Moreover, you can easily walk outside of your array and get UB.

```
char test[MAX] = '';
```

This code initilizes the first element in 'test' array with 0 value so strlen will be able to find it.

Comment: It should be `char test[MAX] = "";`  , the `''` version is a syntax error

Comment: It's true, it was just a typo